# HTemplate is missing in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a simple micropost application using rails...

This is my model :

```
Class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :content, :name
end
```

Controller:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @blog=Micropost.new( :content => params[:content])
        @blog.save
        redirect_to microposts_show_path
    end

    def show
        @mblg=Micropost
    end

    def index
    end    
end
```

Views:

```
create.html.erb

<h1>Microblogs#create</h1>
<p></p>
<%= label_tag(:content) %><br/>
<%= text_field_tag (:content) %><br/>
<%= submit_tag("submit") %><br/>

index.html.erb
<h1>Microblogs#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/microblogs/index.html.erb</p>


show.html.erb
<h1>Microblogs#show</h1>
<p></p>
<%= @mblg.each.do |variable|%>
    <p><%= variable.content %></p>
<%end%>
```

Routes.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  get "microposts/create"

  get "microposts/show"

  get "microposts/index"
end
```

i am getting a template missing error... this is a fairly simple application...can you please point out where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RESTful controller in Rails has hidden actions (create, update, destroy)

The controller (if created as part of the scaffold) will have four actions visible to the user

```
index
new
show
edit
```

In our routes file, you can call

```
resources :microposts
```

which Rails will understand and create the routes for a RESTful controller.

Instead of `/microposts/create` you would use `/microposts/new`

A good example you can look at is a scaffold.

Within your Rails root directory, do the following

```
rails g scaffold foo bar
rake db:migrate
```

You will see that this creates a Foo controller and allows you to new/index/edit/show on this controller. The field that you would be entering and populating is bar.

Once you are finished playing around with this, you can do

```
rails d scaffold foo
rake db:rollback
```